# How to determine equation of a normal to vector parametric curve.

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, curves

If curve is given with $r=r(t)$ vector parametric equation, then equation of tangent line at point $M_0$ corresponding to $t_0$ parameter value is given by

$R(\tau)=r(t_0)+$ $\tau$  $r^\prime(t_0)$ where $\tau$ is parameter. Now I understand how we are getting this equation but have question concerning to normal line.

Line that is passing through a tangent point and is perpendicular to a tangent line is called normal line.

My book mentions that equation of normal will be $(R(\tau)-r(t_0))r^\prime (t_0)=0$.

Can you explain how this equation is derived?

Comment: $(R(\tau) - r(t_0))$ is a vector, and $r'(t_0)$ is a vector.  What is the meaning of $ (R(\tau) - r(t_0) ) r'(t_0) )$ ?  Did you mean cross product between the two vectors ?

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea Book does not mention this but i think it is dot product

Comment: Are you talking about two-dimensional curves or three-dimensional ?

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea book does not mention so I assume it's true for two-dimensional and three-dimensional curves.

Comment: You may wanna check this [page](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Vector_Calculus/2%3A_Vector-Valued_Functions_and_Motion_in_Space/2.3%3A_Curvature_and_Normal_Vectors_of_a_Curve)

Comment: No, two dimensions only! Why?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't know. First i can't understand how that is derived.

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea I checked linked page but couldn't find answer. Can you give some hints?

Comment: In three dimensions there is a normal *plane*, not line. What is the definition of the normal line to a curve in the plane at a point?

Comment: Here is a [Youtube video](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=is+the+normal+to+the+curve+defined+for+three+dimensional+curves&&view=detail&mid=9A0DC29A36425EAD4DC19A0DC29A36425EAD4DC1&&FORM=VDRVRV) that explains to some extent the normal vectors to a 3D parametric curve.

Answer (score 2):

The normal vector N(t) to a curve $r(t)$ is a vector that is perpendicular to the tangent vector $T(t) = r'(t)$.  In two-dimensional curves, it is easy to find the normal vector by rotating the tangent vector by $90^\circ$ either clockwise or anti-clockwise.  If T(t) = (T_x, T_y) then

$N(t) = (-T_y, T_x) $ by a rotation of $90^\circ$ anti-clockwise.

In three-dimensions, the normal vector any vector that perpendicular to the tangent vector $T(t) = r'(t)$, and there is not one vector or two vectors that are perpendicular to the tangent vector, there is an infinite number of normal vectors that lie in the plane that is perpendicular to the T(t) and passing through $r(t_0)$.  That said, a normal vector that lies in the same plane as $(dT(t))$ (a differential of T(t)) is given by

$N(t) = \dfrac{d\hat{T}}{dt} $

where

$ \hat{T}(t) = \dfrac{ T(t) } { \| T(t) \| } $

is the unit vector along the tangent vector (i.e. it is the unit tangent vector).

As an example, let $r(t) = (t, t^2 , t^3) $

Then $T(t) = (1, 2 t, 3 t^2) $

and $\hat{T}(t) = \dfrac{ (1, 2t, 3 t^2) }{ \sqrt{ 1 + 4 t^2 + 9 t^4 } }$

The normal vector is

$ N(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{ (1, 2t, 3t^2) }{ \sqrt{1 + 4 t^2 + 9t^4} } \right) $

Differentiating using the product rule, this becomes

$ N(t) = \dfrac{ (0, 2, 6t ) }{\sqrt{1 + 4 t^2 + 9t^4}} + (1, 2t, 3t^2) \left( (-4 t - 18 t^3 ) ( 1 + 4 t^2 + 9 t^4 )^{-\frac{3}{2}} \right) $

Combining terms,

$N(t) = \dfrac{ (0, 2, 6 t) (1 + 4 t^2 + 9t^4) + (1, 2 t, 3 t^2)( -4 t - 18 t^3) } {(1 + 4 t^2 + 9 t^4 ) ^{\frac{3}{2} }} $

And this simplifies further to

$N(t) = \dfrac{( - 4 t - 18 t^3 , - 18 t^4 + 2 , 6 t + 12 t^3 )}{ ( 1 + 4 t^2 + 9 t^4) ^{\frac{3}{2}}} $

As a check, we can find the dot product between $N(t)$ and $T(t)$

$N(t) \cdot T(t) = \dfrac{( - 4 t - 18 t^3 - 36 t^5 + 4 t + 18 t^3 + 36 t^5 )}{(1 + 4 t^2 + 9 t^4)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = 0 $

So, indeed $N(t)$ is perpendicular to $T(t)$.

Finally, the parametric equation of the normal vector is

$ P(\tau) = r(t_0) + \tau N(t_0) $

Note that we can replace the complicated expression for $N(t)$ with simply $ (  - 2 t - 9 t^3 , - 9 t^4 + 1 , 3 t + 6 t^3 ) $ because $N(t)$ is a scalar multiple of it.

Comment: thanks for answer why $N(t) = \dfrac{d\hat{T}}{dt}$?

Comment: I leave this to you to figure out.  Hint:  The derivative of a unit vector is orthogonal to it.  Prove that.